# Printing tables with page-break in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table, page-break

I have a simple table with many rows and I want to automatically insert page breaks between rows at the end of a page. This seems to work fine by default in Firefox, but Internet Explorer (7-9) doesn't break the table. It the table is too long for one page, the rest of the table rows get lost.

So I tried to use the CSS properties page-break-* in many different ways to fix this, but nothing helped. I found that http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebb.asp says

> "...avoid page-breaking properties inside tables..."

Why does it say that? My table looks like this:

```html
<table class="formatted tablesorter">
    <caption>Some caption</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Header 1</th>
            <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Header 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">Value 1</td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">Value 2</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- many more rows... -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there any way make page breaks work inside tables for Internet Explorer? It would be okay, if I had to use some JavaScript.

Comment: Is there a strong need why you want to do this with a table? It would be cleaner in a table less design IMO... and yes: you really should avoid breaks between table rows. You could only use empty rows if you really had to, and insert sth like `&nbps;` or `<br />` inside this table rows, but I would not recommend that either...

Comment: Can you post the CSS rules that are applicable to this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element that surrounded the table had `overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden;`. That's why the table didn't break.

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't support the `avoid` value, so would work ok in Firefox but IE would not display the same. Do you have example of the CSS you're using?